# Не работает сочетание клавиш CTRL+Y

Tags: windows

Что делать если не работает сочетание клавиш CTRL+Y в Windows 7 Home edition

Comment: то есть вы начинаете писать тут комментарий, жмете `ctrl+z`, набранный текст удаляется, жмете `ctrl+y` и он не возвращается обратно?

Comment: Тут работает , а вот на компьютере не работает. В редакторе не работает , в посковой строке не работает

Comment: а вы думаете оно везде должно работать? где есть поддержка. там работает, где нет - не работает.